# percona pt-table-checksum - Waiting to check replicas for differences

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I have encountered a problem with Percona checksum..

The database contains about 70 tables and the checksum always stucks at the same table?

If the table is dropped the checksum is completed like it should without any problems.. Have tried to empty the table - same issue..

The table exists on the slave, so that can't be the problem

What am I doing wrong?

## table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice_send_log` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

## syntax

```
pt-table-checksum -h localhost -u root -p password --lock-wait-time=50 --nocheck-replication-filters
```

## message

```
Waiting to check replicas for differences: 0% 00:00 remain
```

Comment: what does mysqladmin processlist show as the running proc while this is stuck?

Comment: Same error here, using "pt-table-checksum 2.1.8"...

Comment: Might be because IO or SQL thread on the slave isn't running. Check SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this one, but it on all slaves both SQL and IO threads are running:

In my case I had set the skip counter to a high value. better set that to zero and temporarily skip errors with slave-skip-errors instead if needed.